# Why forward traverse for loop is not working properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This works properly:

```
for(var i = images1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
```

This is not working:

```
for(var i = 0; i < images1.length; i++)
  document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
```

Why above loop is not working properly.

Comment: What is not working? Does it give an error?

Comment: what is the content of images1?

Comment: Is this loop inside another loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `<div id="top">` is placed underneath the pictures (guess based on testing). Because of that, when you move the pictures into `#top`, their position in the DOM changes with each iteration, and as **the images in the array are ordered depending on the DOM position**, the order of the array changes and that causes all the trouble.

For example, see this code (also available on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx3Lnaqd/1/) for testing purposes):

```js
images1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

/*
//This works properly:
for(var i = images1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
*/

//This is not working:
for(var i = 0; i < images1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/" alt="Abstract Pic" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" alt="People Pic" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Sports Pic" />

<div id="top"></div>
```

If you inspect elements, you can see that the People's picture was not moved, and it remains outside of the `#top` div. But if you uncomment the first loop, and comment the second, it will work as expected.

This is because we would be moving the pictures in reversed order (from the last one to the first one), the relative position among them wouldn't change, and the `images` array doesn't change with it then (moving all the pictures successfully into `#top`).

As I mentioned above, the root cause for this behavior is that the `images1` array changes in each iteration. When you call it first (line 0), its values are:

```
[ 0: Abstract, 1: People, 2: Sports]
```

But the order of the array changes with the order of the pictures on the page. Here are the values step by step (at the time of entering the iteration):

**Iteration 1 (i = 0)**:

> ```
> i = 0
> images1 = [ 0: Abstract, 1: People, 2: Sports ]
> images1[i] = Abstract
> ```
>
> Result: Abstract is moved to the #top div, and also to the end of the array (as it's now the last positioned image in the DOM)

**Iteration 2 (i = 1)**:

> ```
> i = 1
> images1 = [ 0: People, 1: Sports, 2: Abstract ]
> images1[i] = Sports
> ```
>
> Result: Sports is moved to the #top div, and to the end of the array. The People picture is ignored, because its index was 0, and we already skipped that one

**Iteration 3 (i = 2)**:

> ```
> i = 2
> images1 = [ 0: People, 1: Abstract, 2: Sports ]
> images1[i] = Sports
> ```
>
> Result: Sports is again moved to the end of the #top div (remains in the same position), and the array stays the same.

---

One solution to this: place the pictures under the `top` div. That way, the order of the pictures will always be the same and both loops will work just fine: (see it also on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx3Lnaqd/2/))

```js
images1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

/*
//This works properly:
for(var i = images1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
*/

//This is not working:
for(var i = 0; i < images1.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("top").appendChild(images1[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/" alt="Abstract Pic" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" alt="People Pic" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Sports Pic" />
```

---

If you cannot change the position of the elements, just the JavaScript, you could create a static copy of the `images1` array, and use that one instead in the loops. Something like this:

```
// create a static duplicate that will not change with the DOM changes
for (var x = 0; x < images1.length; x++) {
    auximages1.push(images1[x]);
}
```

You can see working on this other [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx3Lnaqd/3/).